# Overflow in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

The code is like this

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]; a1 = 0.527; a2 = 0.228; λ = 6 10^-3; r =
  30 10^-6; ω = 2 π*500; η = 
 1.85 10^-5; ϵr = 3.2; ϵ0 = 
 8.854187817 10^-12; ρ = 1.18 10^3; g = 9.8;
 m = 4/3 π r^3 ρ; Ec = 3 10^6; qmax = 
 4 π r^2 ϵ0 *(3 ϵr)/(ϵr + 2) Ec; q = 
 0.1 qmax; V0 = 1000;
Ex[x_, y_, t_] := 
  V0 ((6 π)/λ a2 Exp[(-4 π)/λ y] Sin[(
        4 π)/λ x + ω t]);
Exx[x_, y_, t_] := 
  V0 ((6 π)/λ*(
     4 π)/λ a2 Exp[(-4 π)/λ y] Cos[(
        4 π)/λ x + ω t]);
Exy[x_, y_, t_] := 
  V0 ((6 π)/λ*(-4 π)/λ a2 Exp[(-4 π)/\
λ y] Sin[(4 π)/λ x + ω t]);
Ey[x_, y_, t_] := 
  V0 ((6 π)/λ a2 Exp[(-4 π)/λ y] Cos[(
        4 π)/λ x + ω t]);
Eyx[x_, y_, t_] := 
  V0 ((6 π)/λ*(-4 π)/λ a2 Exp[(-4 π)/\
λ y] Sin[(4 π)/λ x + ω t]);
Eyy[x_, y_, t_] := 
  V0 ((6 π)/λ*(-4 π)/λ a2 Exp[(-4 π)/\
λ y] Cos[(4 π)/λ x + ω t]);
T = 6 π η r/m;
C1 = q/m;
k1 = (4 π r^3)/m ϵ0 *(ϵr - 1)/(ϵr + 2);
RMS = 3 10^-9; Ah = 10^-19; D1 = 10^-10; γ = 20 10^-9;
w1[y_] := 0 /; y != r
w1[y_] := 154.73 /; y == r
M = q^2/(16 π ϵ0 m); x0 = 
 6.3 10^-3; y0 = r; timelimit = 1;
s = NDSolve[{x''[t] == -T x'[t] + C1*Ex[x[t], y[t], t] + 
      k1*(Ex[x[t], y[t], t] Exx[x[t], y[t], t] + 
         Ey[x[t], y[t], t] Eyx[x[t], y[t], t]), 
    y''[t] == -T y'[t] + C1*Ey[x[t], y[t], t] + 
      k1*(Ex[x[t], y[t], t] Exy[x[t], y[t], t] + 
         Ey[x[t], y[t], t] Eyy[x[t], y[t], t]) - g - w1[y[t]] - 
      M *1/y[t]^2, x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0, x'[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[y[t] == y0, y'[t] -> - y'[t]]}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 
    timelimit}, StartingStepSize -> 10^-5, 
   Method -> {"ExplicitEuler"}];
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. s], {t, 0, 0.5}, 
 Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

In the `NDSolve`, I used `w1[y_] := 0 /; y != r w1[y_] := 154.73 /; y == r` to represent a boundary condition
The overflow comes when I set initial value of **y=r**, if I increase the initial value of **y to 2r**, the error will disappear. However, the initial value of y can effect the simulation result. How can I set initial value of y=r and get result.

[image]

Comment: Function `w1[ y[t]] ` is not contribute to the force, since it is nonzero in one point only . 
But it is not continues or `Piecewise`, it is why `NDSolve` can' t integrate it well. I can recommend to remove `w1[y[t]] ` from equation or redefine this function as continues or `Piecewise` .

Comment: This force only exist when simulate particle contact with the surface, so how can I embed this force into calculation?

Comment: My first reaction is why `Method -> {"ExplicitEuler"}`? Try it with `Method -> Automatic`.

Comment: @Michael, thanks a lot! it works fine when the method is automatic. I am not familiar with NDsovle.

Comment: @Michael, the trajectories will be different when I use different methods. So how can I know which method is more accurate?

Comment: @Yuuu You can integrate around contact and add result to the `y'[t]` in `WhenEvent[]`. What kind of force do you try to simulate with  `w1`?

Comment: @Alex, w1 is the adhesion force and the value of this force is 154.73.

Comment: @Yuuu There is no any equation to simulate collision of particles with solid surface  in your system. Why do you try to include some forces in the dynamic equation? Better you use   `y'[t] -> -k y'[t]]` with `k<=1` dependent on adhesion, elastic force and so on.